# CAML Query to Get Single List Item Failing

Tags: javascript, csom, caml, sp.js, script-webpart

So this is about the third script I've copied (this time from C# Corner) in an attempt to get a CAML query working but as with the others, I can't get it to work. Starting to get pretty upset about it tbh.

I need it to pick a single item from 'DSHaveYouMet' based on the number field 'scriptIndex' (this will be passed in as a variable but doing it with manual values atm). I've set up a page with the list in an App Part and a Script Editor WP with the code below in it. Every time I hit the button to trigger the async function, it returns the onFailedCallBack error; no errors in the F12 console either before or after clicking the button, not even a warning.

Code I'm using below:

```
<div><button onclick=" queryListItems ()">Click here to Create a List</button></div>  

<div id="displayDiv"></div>  
   <script type="text/javascript">  
      //This example gets all the items in the Announcements list that have a title that begins with 'T'.  
      //If your site doesn't include a list called Announcements you must make the changes indicated  

      //This variable will hold a reference to the Announcements list items collection  
      var returnedItems = null;  

      //This function loads the list and runs the query asynchronously  
      function queryListItems() {  
         //Get the current context  
         var context = new SP.ClientContext();  
         //Get the Announcements list. Alter this code to match the name of your list  
         var list = context.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('DSHaveYouMet');  
         //Create a new CAML query  
         var caml = new SP.CamlQuery();  
         //Create the CAML that will return only items with the titles that begin with 'T'  
         caml.set_viewXml("<View><Query><Where><FieldRef Name='ID' /><Value Type='Number'>234</Value></Where></Query></View>");  
         //Specify the query and load the list oject  
         returnedItems = list.getItems(caml);  
         context.load(returnedItems);  
         //Run the query asynchronously, passing the functions to call when a response arrives  
         context.executeQueryAsync(onSucceededCallback, onFailedCallback);  
      }  

      //This function fires when the query completes successfully  
      function onSucceededCallback(sender, args) {  
         //Get an enumerator for the items in the list  
         var enumerator = returnedItems.getEnumerator();  
         //Formulate HTML from the list items  
         var markup = 'Items in the Announcements list that start with "T": <br><br>';  
         //Loop through all the items  
         while (enumerator.moveNext()) {  
         var listItem = enumerator.get_current();  
         markup += 'Item Title: ' + listItem.get_item('hymDisplayName') + '<br>';  
      }  
      //Display the formulated HTML in the displayDiv element  
      displayDiv.innerHTML = markup;  
   }  
   //This function fires when the query fails  
   function onFailedCallback(sender, args) {  
      //Formulate HTML to display details of the error  
      var markup = '<p>The request failed: <br>';  
      markup += 'Message: ' + args.get_message() + '<br>';  
      //Display the details  
      displayDiv.innerHTML = markup;  
   }  
</script>
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have missed `<Eq></Eq>`

try following query

```
<View><Query><Where><Eq><FieldRef Name='ID' /><Value Type='Number'>234</Value></Where></Eq></Query></View>
```

Or If you want to get Item using ID Instated of caml Query `getItemById()` method.

Try following code.

```
function queryListItems() {  
         //Get the current context  
         var context = new SP.ClientContext();  
         //Get the Announcements list. Alter this code to match the name of your list  
         var list = context.get_web().get_lists().getByTitle('DSHaveYouMet');  
         var item=  list.getItemById(234);          
         context.load(item);  
         //Run the query asynchronously, passing the functions to call when a response arrives  
         context.executeQueryAsync(onSucceededCallback, onFailedCallback);  
      }
```

Comment: Ahh I knew it'd be something basic like that. Thanks, working fine now. :)